# Can I create Background Services on Android using Phonegap Build?

Tags: service, background, cordova, phonegap-build

I have been developing a phonegap application (HTML/jQuery) for Android devices and packing it in *Phonegap Build*.

I have a demand of having a **background service** that keep sending data to our web services every 1 minute. As far as I heard, it's only possible developing the background service in Java and communicating with the UI somehow.

My background is in .NET, so my question is: Is there another way of doing that apart from Java? Any good tutorial?

If not, Can I still keep using *PhoneGap Build* to pack the *UI* and the *Background Service*? Or do I have to have the whole Phonegap SDK installed in my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it by Phonegap Build!

You have to install the whole set of tools (eclipse, android sdk and cordova), and then develop the service in `Java`, adding your `HTML` assets into the project. So that you'll get able to generate the APK containg Background Service and Webapp.